# Запуск/остановка на конкретную дату

Tags: java, планировщик-задач, quartz

День добрый.
Возникла необходимость создания планировщика заданий. Почитав интернет везде рекомендует использовать Quartz. Но я не со всем понимаю как создать то что мне надо:
У меня есть база данных с днями рождениями клиентов. Суть в том что на 1 число текущего месяца необходимо сформировать список клиентов с др, у каждого клиента есть столбец GIFT. Его суть в том, что на дни рождения в этот столбец будет начисляться бонусные баллы. Так вот необходимость состоит в том что. Нужно создавать н-количество задач которые будут начислять эти бонусы. То есть в задачу надо передавать id_cliet и sum_gift. Причем каждую задачу надо выполнить строго за день до его дня рождения. А затем спустя день после его дня рождения выполнить вторую, которая удалит бонусы если они не были использованы.

Для этих целей не плохо подошел этот код. Но есть нюанс, я не понимаю как в него передать нужные мне значения для аппдейтов. И привязать его к дате выполнения.

```
public class QuartzJob implements Job {

public QuartzJob(){

}
@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
    System.out.println(jobExecutionContext.getTrigger());
}
}

 JobDetail job = JobBuilder
                .newJob(QuartzJob.class)
                .withIdentity("QuartzJob", "group1")
                .build();

        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
                .newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("QuartzTrigger", "group1")
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder
                        .cronSchedule("0 48 9-18/1 ? * MON,TUE,WED"))
                .build();


        SchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        Scheduler sched = schedFact.getScheduler();
        sched.start();
        sched.scheduleJob(job,trigger);
```

Всем кто откликнется спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Логика не та. Вам не нужно плодить кучу заданий. Достаточно одной задачи, которая будет обращаться прямо в момент выполнения в бд, брать всех юзеров и проходится по ним делая то что Вам нужно. Запускать можно, допустим в конце дня, то бишь в полночь. Ну в момент выполнения вы уже смотрите если дата рождения юзера совпадает со следующим днем то начисляете бонусы, если же дата рождения после списываете бонусы.

```
public class CronUsers implements Job {

        @Override
        public void execute(JobExecutionContext ctx) throws JobExecutionException {

            // Определяем текущую дату. Можно заодно предыдущую и следующую.

            Calendar C = Calendar.getInstance(); 

            Date current = C.getTime();// текущая

            C.add(Calendar.DATE, -1); // минус один день

            Date yesterday = C.getTime();

            C.add(Calendar.Date, 2); // добавляем два дня (учитываем что отнимали в предыдущем действии один день.

            Date tomorrow = C.getTime();

            // Обращаетесь к бд. Получаете список пользователей

            List<User> users = DataBase.getUsers();

            users.stream().forEach(user=>{
               Date birthday = user.getBirthDay(); // преобразуем строку с датой рождения в объект Date. Можно воспользоваться SimpleDateFormat.

               // Делаем проверки на даты и пишем в базу

            });

        }
    }
```

Comment: В принципе идея очень хороша, но есть нюанс, эти бонусы могут начислить всем пользователям одновременно. То есть надо отслеживать заданную сумму на дни рождения То есть заюзать проперти какие-нибудь.

Comment: И такой вопрос можно ли сделать так чтобы задание не крутилось бесконтрльно, А скажем по истечению заданных дат останавливалось?

Comment: @АндрейСосновский не начислят всем одновременно. Вы будете давать бонусы только конкретному юзеру в цикле.
А смысл? задание будет запускаться один раз в день, в полночь ( желательно где-то перед 00:00).
Quartz поддерживает `cron expressions`. Вот сайт для составления - http://www.cronmaker.com/

Comment: Я скорее всего не так выразился. Просто предположим что администратор решит начислить 1 апреля всем пользователям какую-то сумму. И получится сумма на день рождение плюс сумма на 1 апреля. При проходе задачей по обнулению дней рождений обнулит и ту и ту.

Comment: @АндрейСосновский так бонусы даются на один день. Даже если др в 1 апреля они оба подлежат списыванию. или я не так понял?

Comment: Простите это я не много запутался. Спасибо вам большое!

Comment: Единственное как все таки установить на конкретную дату. Скажем на первое апреля?

Comment: @АндрейСосновский на сайте http://www.cronmaker.com/ можно сделать. Получится такое: `0 50 23 1 4 ? *`. Вкладка Yearly

Comment: Все понял. Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Либо я тормоз либо что-то еще. А как мы сравним дату рождения к примеру 30.03.1995 с датой 28.03.2018?

Comment: @АндрейСосновский у `Date` есть методы стравнения

Comment: Я сделал по другому тяну просто. Тяну прямо из базы за конкретный период и форматирую

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста. А как в этот класс передать значение этого бонуса. Дело в том что при начисление на дни рождения он будет статичен. А вот бонусы которые будут разово начислятся необходимо передать значение суммы. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста. А как в этот класс передать значение этого бонуса. Дело в том что при начисление на дни рождения он будет статичен. А вот бонусы которые будут разово начислятся необходимо передать значение суммы. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: @АндрейСосновский взять из базы или из конфига где хранить оно. Или в этом классе объявить как статическое финальное поле.